# Distributed system facebook

Tags: java, facebook, distributed-system

Does anyone know how to answer these questions or where I would find information on this?
How does Facebook deal with Timing issues/synchronisation?
How does Facebook deal with multiple architectures/file systems?
How does Facebook deal with critical resources and the fair and equitable sharing of the same?
Does Facebook behave as a real time system as well as being a distributed system and if so how does Facebook manage deadlines?
Is Facebook a client-server or peer-to-peer system and if so how?
How is data transferred so that there is no corruption of data on Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following concepts to get an idea.
The domain of your question is quite huge.

- Timing issues:

  - [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)
  - [Vector clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock#:%7E:text=A%20vector%20clock%20is%20a,the%20sending%20process%27s%20logical%20clock.)
- Multiple architecture handled by clear, concise interface.
- Critical issue management is mostly done by replication, failover by standby server.
- Facebook is client-server with servers acting peer to peer to replicate, syncronise.
- Data transfer to avoid corruption

  - [Erasure code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasure_code)